# how to make parent controller and instantiate in php

Tags: php, class, inheritance

i have multiple controller like registerController, loginController, boardController

and those controllers have same dependency of authentication.

in code

```
$registerController = new Register($authentication);
$loginController = new Login($authentication);
$shopController = new Shop();
$boardController = new Board($authentication);
```

so im trying to make parent class for those contorllers that named BaseController.
so child Controllers can inherite same authentication instance.

```
class BaseController {
    public $authentication;
 
    public function __construct($authentication) {
        $this->authentication = $authentication;
    }
}
```

one of my ChildController looks like this

```
class Shop extends BaseController{
    public function __construct() {}

    public function checkParentAuth(){
        var_dump($this->authentication); // it shows NULL
    }
}
```

i wish the code look like this

```
new BaseController($authentication);
$registerController = new Register();
$loginController = new Login();
$shopController = new Shop();
$boardController = new Board();
```

what should i do for this?
i thought it will surely works...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing call the parent contructor, which will run all stuff necessary to activate and fill values the properties/variables

```php
class Orders extends Site_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    //first, call the parent constructor
    parent::__construct();
    ...
    //your code goes here.
  }
}
```